# LogstashEncoder utf-8 not working

Tags: java, logging, utf-8, catalina

when I use **net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder** output chinese words to log file, they always change to unicode char, like *\u5FAE\u670D\u52A1\u51FA\u9519\uFF0C\u8BF7*,
  I've tried config **charset=utf-8** whin LogstashEncoder, but it's not working,
  Could someone tell me what can i do? thank you!
  my logback.xml:

```
<appender name="stash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/sublogs/development.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/sublogs/development.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
          <charset>UTF-8</charset>    
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use charset="UTF-8" as argument. It works for me:

```
<encoder charset="UTF-8" class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
```